# Fullcalendar on Rails, different colors for different tasks

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, fullcalendar

I am trying to edit Jquery Fullcalendar that is running on my rails application. I cant figure out how to make it recognize different types of tasks, which come from the same source, and style them according to their type. I followed this https://github.com/bokmann/fullcalendar-rails as an example when I was implementing it.

Honestly I can't even understand how the style is getting set at all. Even just manually setting the colors doesn't seem to change anything, it's always just black text with a yellow background on the current day. I've tried a number of solutions to similar problems that I've seen on here but either they didn't work or I didn't understand them correctly and did something wrong.

Comment: Try passing a different CSS class for every different type of task. Just a thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easily done. You just need to set the className in the source object.
It took quite a few levels of CSS selectors to override the default style options, see what works in your case.

CSS:

```
.fc-content .fc-view .localSource2 div.fc-event-inner {
  background: red;
} /* you might want to trim this selector down, but it worked for me */
```

Javascript:

```
localSource = {
  events: [ {title: 'All Day Event', start: new Date(y, m, 1)}, 
            /* More Event Data here */ ],
  className: 'localSource', // an option!
  currentTimezone: 'Europe/Bucharest', // an option!        
}; 
USHolidays = {
  url: 'http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/usa__en%40holiday.calendar.google.com/public/full',    
  className: 'gcal-event', // an option!
  currentTimezone: 'America/Chicago', // an option!
};
options = {
    eventSources: [localSource, USHolidays]
};

fullCalendar(options); // EventSources are set in options
```

[Event Source Documentation](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Source_Object/) mentions other properties too (color, textcolor).